# Create a nested collection without relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, nested

I want to create a nested collection but i'm not using relationship because the data comes from API.

the array should be displayed like this:

- route: us
- lat: xxx
- long: xxx
- destination: -> name: good park, address: xxx street,
  -> name: bad park, address: xxx street,

right now, my array still separated, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: add more information in your question. Its very unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and specifically how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a collection:

```
$collection = collect([]);
```

Then populate your collection from the API.  I'm not sure what format the information is in, but you will need to do something similar to:

`$collection = ['route' => 'us', 'lat' => 'xxx', 'long' => 'xxx', 'destination' => ['good-park' => 'street-address', 'bad-park' => 'street-address']];`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#creating-collections